# Formulario POST no envía, error 400 (bad request)

Tags: php, html, formularios

buenas tengo este formulario como ejercicio y resulta que cada vez que relleno los campos y le doy al boton de enviar me alerta con el error de "Please complete the form and try again." Aunque los haya rellenado, tengo conocimientos muy basicos de PHP y no consigo ver por donde esta el error, espero puedan ayudarme.

El formulario:

```
<div class="form-wrapper col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-12">
<form name="contact" method="POST" action="php/process-form.php">
<div class="form-group clearfix">
<div class="inner-form-group">
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="inner-form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="asunto" placeholder="Asunto" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit">
<span class="front">
<i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
<span class="value">Enviar <span>Mensaje</span></span>
</span>
<span class="back">
<i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
<span class="value">Enviar <span>Mensaje</span></span>
</span>
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

El "php/process-form.php":

```
<?php 

require("PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php");
require("PHPMailer/SMTP.php");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") :

    // Sender Data
    $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST["name"]));
    $email = filter_var(trim(strip_tags($_POST["email"])), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = trim(strip_tags($_POST["subject"]));
    $message = trim(htmlentities($_POST["message"]));

    if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) :
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    else : 
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) : 
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Invalid email format.";
            exit;
        endif;
    endif;


    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; // Make instance PHPMailer


    // RECIPIENTS
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name); // Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->addAddress('info@jmjs.soy', 'José María Jurado Soler'); // Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name); //Set an alternative reply-to address
    

    // CONTENT
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject; // This is the subject

    // This is the HTML message body
    $mail->Body = "<b>Nombre</b>: $name<br><b>Email</b>: $email<br><br><b>Mensaje</b>: $message"; 

    // This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
    $mail->AltBody = "Nombre: $name\nEmail: $email\n\nMensaje: $message";


    // Send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) :
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500); // Failed
    else : 
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Gracias! Hemos recibido tu mensaje."; // Success
    endif;

else :
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code
    http_response_code(403);
endif;
```

?>

El Servidor SMTP funciona correctamente. Cada vez que envió el formulario, me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el inspector del navegador, me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como he dicho estoy aprendiendo y cualquier respuesta me ayudaria a crecer y aprender, espero sepan guiarme un poco saludos.

He encontrado en los archivos JS (el unico legible) el custom.js que contiene lo que creo es la validacion. ¿que opinan?

```
    // Process Contact Form
metronal.processContactForm = function() {
    var form = $('form[name="contact"]'),
        message = $('.contact-msg'),
        formData;

    // Success Function
    var doneFunc = function(response) {
        message.text(response);
        message
            .removeClass('alert-danger')
            .addClass('alert-success')
            .fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 2400);
        form.find('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').val('');
    };

    // Fail Function
    var failFunc = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(jqXHR.status === 400) {
            message.text(jqXHR.responseText);
        } else {
            message.text(jqXHR.statusText);
        }
        message
            .removeClass('alert-success')
            .addClass('alert-danger')
            .fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 2400);
    };

    // Form On Submit 
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(doneFunc)
        .fail(failFunc);
    });
};
```

Es esta una validación Front? Disculpen mi nivel, pero estoy en plena formación.

Arbol de directorios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Depurando la variable "var_dump($_POST)":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu PHP tienes varios condicionales que te lanzan un código `400`, me refiero a los `if` donde tienes esto: `http_response_code(400);`. Depura tu script, pues parece que una de esas condiciones se está cumpliendo. Si quieres que te ayudemos mejor muéstranos el resultado de un `var_dump($_POST);` en ese escenario.

Comment: Por ejemplo, el `input` para el asunto tiene `name="asunto"`, y en PHP lo intentas recuperar como: `$subject = trim(strip_tags($_POST["subject"]));`, tú debes usar en el POST lo que hayas puesto en la etiqueta `name` del `input`, por tanto, para esa variable, deberías ponerlo así: `$subject = trim(strip_tags($_POST["asunto"]));` Viendo un `var_dump($_POST);` podrás verificar lo que está llegando y hacer que cada cosa coincida.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo la guía que necesitaba.

Comment: El problema es que no puedo ver la variable $_POST ya que no llega a enviarse, el problema, creo que esta en la validacion, me alerta con que "complete el formulario" pero el formulario esta completo.

Comment: ¿Te alerta dónde, en Javascript? Muestra el tipo de validación que estás implementando.

Comment: quita los "required" (q hacen la validation en front)  en tu HTML para probar si el error viene de tu PHP o del HTML

Comment: @A.Cedano Voy a comprobar quien hace la validación, pero lo que esta ocurriendo es que me indica que los campos están vacíos, aunque los rellene. Creo es de archivo "process-form.php". Muchas gracias están siendo de mucha ayuda para mi.

Comment: @skytorner  Probare quitando los "required" y si no funciona, intentare crear un archivo JS para la validación. Pero creo que en el archivo PHP lo que esta ocurriendo es esto: 
" 

    if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) :
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit; "

Comment: entiendo ! tienes en cuenta que no hay codigo para decir cual input no esta rellenado y todavia el formulario sabe cual es y eso no es automatico , por eso q pienso que el error viene del html

Comment: Si, cada vez que indago mas, veo que el problema es en la validación (creo front con JS) y el archivo "process-form" es la validación back-end que no llega a ejecutarse por no superar la primera validación. No sabría que cambiar en el HTML para ver el error, se me ocurre hacer una validación nueva con JS y ponerla en el HTML. @skytorner

Comment: Si pones `var_dump($_POST);` en el archivo `.php` que procesa el formulario, deberías ver en pantalla lo que ese archivo está recibiendo, no entiendo por qué dices que no tienes acceso a `$_POST` ¿? Lo que intuyo es que estás poniendo las cosas en el `.php` equivocado, quizá porque el archivo que pones en el `action` del `form` es otro. Revisa que esa es la ruta. Si no sabes revisarlo, muéstranos como tienes tu árbol de directorios, donde veamos la ubicación del archivo del `form`  y del archivo que tienes en el `action`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya puse el árbol de directorios y cuando depuro el archivo "process-form.php". Solo me da de información: "array(0)"

Comment: ¿El formulario en qué archivo está y en qué carpeta está ese archivo? ¿Qué URL ves en la barra de navegación cuando abres el formulario y qué URL ves cuando éste se envía?

Comment: One moment: no había visto que estás usando Ajax. Pon un `console.log(formData);` debajo de esto:  `formData = $(this).serialize();` y revisa en la consola si ves los datos del formulario. En algunos servidores no es posible recoger los datos pasados con `FormData` por POST directamente, hay que hacer algo como: `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); var_dump($_POST);` prueba de ese modo y dime si ves los datos ahora.

Comment: He editado el arbol de directorios y he puesto los que se ve en el inspector de elementos, te dejo la web publica con el error, por si quieres inspeccionar, yo estoy trabjando esto en Localhost.
http://jmjs.soy/#contact
@A.Cedano Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: has quitado los "required" en tu HTML ? creo q deberias probar eso 1ero y  luego ver que tiene la variable $_POST antes de ir mas adelante con la validation

Comment: Intenta verificar el POST como te dije en mi anterior comentario, y pon el `console.log` que te dije, para verificar que se están recogiendo los datos correctamente con FormData. Tienes también errores 404 que conviene corregir.

Comment: @skytorner Quitándolo, igualmente me pide que rellene el formulario aunque este completo. Voy a probar buscar que datos recoge la variable $_POST, y ver como avanza esto. Gracias a los dos.